# Convert a single data frame into list of data frames (parsing column names into prefixes and suffixes)

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am hoping to determine an efficient way to convert a single data frame into a list of data frames. Below is my reproducible MWE:

```
set.seed(1)
ABAge = runif(100)
ABPoints = rnorm(100)
ACAge = runif(100)
ACPoints = rnorm(100)
BCAge = runif(100)
BCPoints = rnorm(100)

A_B <- data.frame(ID = as.character(paste0("ID", 1:100)), Age = ABAge, Points = ABPoints)
A_C <- data.frame(ID = as.character(paste0("ID", 1:100)), Age = ACAge, Points = ACPoints)
B_C <- data.frame(ID = as.character(paste0("ID", 1:100)), Age = BCAge, Points = BCPoints)
A_B$ID <- as.character(A_B$ID)
A_C$ID <- as.character(A_C$ID)
B_C$ID <- as.character(B_C$ID)

listFormat <- list("A_B" = A_B, "A_C" = A_C, "B_C" = B_C)

dfFormat <- data.frame(ID = as.character(paste0("ID", 1:100)), A_B.Age = ABAge, A_B.Points = ABPoints, A_C.Age = ACAge, A_C.Points = ACPoints, B_C.Age = BCAge, B_C.Points = BCPoints)
dfFormat$ID = as.character(dfFormat$ID)
```

This results in a data frame format (`dfFormat`) that looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ ID        : chr  "ID1" "ID2" "ID3" "ID4" ...
 $ A_B.Age   : num  0.266 0.372 0.573 0.908 0.202 ...
 $ A_B.Points: num  0.398 -0.612 0.341 -1.129 1.433 ...
 $ A_C.Age   : num  0.6737 0.0949 0.4926 0.4616 0.3752 ...
 $ A_C.Points: num  0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ B_C.Age   : num  0.814 0.929 0.147 0.75 0.976 ...
 $ B_C.Points: num  1.474 0.677 0.38 -0.193 1.578 ...
```

and a list of data frames `listFormat` that looks like this:

```
List of 3
 $ A_B:'data.frame':    100 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ ID    : chr [1:100] "ID1" "ID2" "ID3" "ID4" ...
  ..$ Age   : num [1:100] 0.266 0.372 0.573 0.908 0.202 ...
  ..$ Points: num [1:100] 0.398 -0.612 0.341 -1.129 1.433 ...
 $ A_C:'data.frame':    100 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ ID    : chr [1:100] "ID1" "ID2" "ID3" "ID4" ...
  ..$ Age   : num [1:100] 0.6737 0.0949 0.4926 0.4616 0.3752 ...
  ..$ Points: num [1:100] 0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ B_C:'data.frame':    100 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ ID    : chr [1:100] "ID1" "ID2" "ID3" "ID4" ...
  ..$ Age   : num [1:100] 0.814 0.929 0.147 0.75 0.976 ...
  ..$ Points: num [1:100] 1.474 0.677 0.38 -0.193 1.578 ...
```

I am hoping to come up with an automated way to convert the `dfFormat` to `listFormat`. As can be seen in the above objects there are two main conditions:

1. The column `ID` is always the first column in `dfFormat` and it is always the first column in each sublist of `listFormat`.
2. The number of sublists is equal to the number of unique column names in `dfFormat` before the underscore ('_'). In this case, that is three prefixes (ex. "A_B", "A_C", and "B_C"). These prefixes are also the names of the three sublists.
3. Within each sublist, it contains the number of columns that had the associated prefix ("A_B"). For each sublist, this was two ("Age" and "Points"). These suffixes are the names of the columns.

I asked the reverse question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248706/convert-a-list-of-data-frames-into-a-single-data-frame-with-list-name) (i.e. how to go from `listFormat` to `dfFormat`) and got some helpful answers that I am learning from. I need to have code to reverse both directions and it seems the reverse direction may need new types of code. I put my attempt below to show how I am stuck!

```
conUnd <- which(sapply(colnames(dfFormat), function(x) grepl("_", x)))
listName <- sapply(colnames(dfFormat[,conUnd]), function(x) strsplit(x, "[.]")[[1]][1])
uListName <- unique(sapply(colnames(dfFormat[,conUnd]), function(x) strsplit(x, "[.]")[[1]][1]))
listCol <- sapply(colnames(dfFormat[,conUnd]), function(x) strsplit(x, "[.]")[[1]][2])

listFormat = list()
for (i in 1:length(uListName)){
   [Gets messy here trying to define column names based on string variables]
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I know my code is not efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `split.default` in base R -

```
output <- lapply(split.default(dfFormat[-1], sub("\\..*", "",names(dfFormat[-1]))), 
          function(x) cbind(dfFormat[1], setNames(x, sub(".*\\.", "", names(x)))))
str(output)

#List of 3
# $ A_B:'data.frame':   100 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ ID    : chr [1:100] "ID1" "ID2" "ID3" "ID4" ...
#  ..$ Age   : num [1:100] 0.266 0.372 0.573 0.908 0.202 ...
#  ..$ Points: num [1:100] 0.398 -0.612 0.341 -1.129 1.433 ...
# $ A_C:'data.frame':   100 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ ID    : chr [1:100] "ID1" "ID2" "ID3" "ID4" ...
#  ..$ Age   : num [1:100] 0.6737 0.0949 0.4926 0.4616 0.3752 ...
#  ..$ Points: num [1:100] 0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
# $ B_C:'data.frame':   100 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ ID    : chr [1:100] "ID1" "ID2" "ID3" "ID4" ...
#  ..$ Age   : num [1:100] 0.814 0.929 0.147 0.75 0.976 ...
#  ..$ Points: num [1:100] 1.474 0.677 0.38 -0.193 1.578 ...
```

Comment: I think it would improve SO if downvoters were *required* to give a reason.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the `tidyverse`. It involves converting the data frame to long format, split the columns, spread it, ans the split the data frame based on the group name. In the last line, `as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` is not necessary as `tibble` is also a `data frame`. I added it so that I can show you the output is the same as your expected list.

```
library(tidyverse)

listFormat_output <- dfFormat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = "Type") %>%
  separate(Type, into = c("Group", "Parameter"), sep = "\\.") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Parameter) %>%
  group_split(Group) %>%
  setNames(nm = map_chr(., ~unique(.x$Group))) %>%
  map(~.x %>% select(-Group) %>% as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

# Check if the output is the same as the expected list
identical(listFormat, listFormat_output)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score -2):

Using `mget`, `ls`, and regular expression seems to get what you want.

**DATA**:

*Edit*:
Your dataframe `dfFormat`, which has this structure:

```
str(dfFormat)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ ID        : chr  "ID1" "ID2" "ID3" "ID4" ...
 $ A_B.Age   : num  0.266 0.372 0.573 0.908 0.202 ...
 $ A_B.Points: num  0.398 -0.612 0.341 -1.129 1.433 ...
 $ A_C.Age   : num  0.6737 0.0949 0.4926 0.4616 0.3752 ...
 $ A_C.Points: num  0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ B_C.Age   : num  0.814 0.929 0.147 0.75 0.976 ...
 $ B_C.Points: num  1.474 0.677 0.38 -0.193 1.578 ...
```

**SOLUTION**:

The solution picks up on the column names in `dfFormat`, matching the columns by which you want to convert the dataframe into a list of dataframes using regex:

```
listFormat <-  mget(ls(pattern = "^A_B|^A_C|^B_C"))
```

**RESULT**:

```
str(listFormat)
List of 3
 $ A_B:'data.frame':    100 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ ID    : chr [1:100] "ID1" "ID2" "ID3" "ID4" ...
  ..$ Age   : num [1:100] 0.266 0.372 0.573 0.908 0.202 ...
  ..$ Points: num [1:100] 0.398 -0.612 0.341 -1.129 1.433 ...
 $ A_C:'data.frame':    100 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ ID    : chr [1:100] "ID1" "ID2" "ID3" "ID4" ...
  ..$ Age   : num [1:100] 0.6737 0.0949 0.4926 0.4616 0.3752 ...
  ..$ Points: num [1:100] 0.409 1.689 1.587 -0.331 -2.285 ...
 $ B_C:'data.frame':    100 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ ID    : chr [1:100] "ID1" "ID2" "ID3" "ID4" ...
  ..$ Age   : num [1:100] 0.814 0.929 0.147 0.75 0.976 ...
  ..$ Points: num [1:100] 1.474 0.677 0.38 -0.193 1.578 ...
```

Comment: Could the person who downvoted please leave a hint at why they did?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I think you probably misunderstood the question so you got a downvote. The question is how to convert `dfFormat` to `listFormat`, not assemble a list from `A_B`, `A_C`, and `B_C`. We have to assume that A_B`, `A_C`, and `B_C` are not in the working space.

Comment: The OP states "I am hoping to come up with an automated way to convert the `dfFormat` to `listFormat`"--that's exactly what my answer does.

Comment: As I stated, we have no idea if `A_B`, `A_C`, and `B_C` are in OP's working space. We have to assume they are not there and the solution needs to start with `dfFormat`. This is my interpretation. You can wait for OP's clarification if he or she wants to.

Comment: I agree with www. I didn't downvote. But the OP was after a way to convert a "single" data frame into a list of data frames. You've provided a nice way to convert "multiple" data frames into a list of data frames. You need to start with `dfFormat`. Read the title of his question again.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, both @Edward and @www. My solution does start from a single dataframe, namely OP's data frame `dfFormat`. If that dataframe is in the working space, the solution provided works.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I respectfully disagree. Your solution started with `A_B`, `A_C`, and `B_C`, not `dfFormat`. If you showed how you created `A_B`, `A_C`, and `B_C` from `dfFormat`, then I agree with you that you started with `dfFormat`. Please notice that in the real world OP may not have `A_B`, `A_C`, and `B_C`, only  `dfFormat`.

Comment: @www The columns names of `dfFormat` contain the strings `A_B`, `A_C`, and `B_C`; using regex they can be matched.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I tested your solution. It seems like if we remove `A_B`, `A_C`, and `B_C` first by `rm(A_B)`, `rm(A_C)`, and `rm(B_C)`, your solution will get an empty list. This means your solution is matching the data frames `A_B`, `A_C`, and `B_C`, not the column names in `dfFormat`.

Comment: @www Sorry, disagree. If I do `rm(A_B); rm(A_C); rm(B_C); rm(dfFormat); rm(listFormat)` and start from scratch it all works fine.

Comment: @Chris. Start from `dfFormat` only. Nothing else in workspace. Does your solution work?

Comment: I don't understand how your`ls` can match the column names in `dfFormat`. If you can show that, I am willing to give you an upvote.

Comment: I also did not downvote any of these answers. They have all been helpful; I am learning lots of new techniques. I should have stated clearly that, in my mind, I was hoping to find a solution that did not start with `A_B`, `A_C`, and 'B_C` in the working space. But this solution can certainly still be helpful.

Comment: @ everybody involved in this lengthy discussion: I feel I owe an apology. I *did* overlook the fact that I should have removed the dataframes `A_B`, `A_C`, and `B_C` **after** defining them; thus the df's *were* of course in the working space. So what my solution provides is, as @Edward noted, a way to convert "multiple" data frames into a list of data frames.